# saveFrame produces NullPointerException Error

Tags: python, processing

I am still new to Processing and I am using Python but seemingly the compiler is producing a `NullPointerException` error. How to fix this?

If it helps, I am using Windows.

This is the original program code-

```
def setup():
    size(400, 400)
    stroke(255)

def draw():
    line(150, 25, mouseX, mouseY)

def mousePressed():
    background(192, 64, 0)

saveFrame("output.png")
```

````
processing.app.SketchException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.saveFrame(PApplet.java:3984)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:188)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:206)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:497)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:501)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:141)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx387.f$0(sketch_190727c.pyde:1)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx387.call_function(sketch_190727c.pyde)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:171)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1614)
    at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java:1658)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx386.f$0(C:/Users/Abi/AppData/Local/Temp/sketch_190727c1462189324264258430/sketch_190727c.pyde:96)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx386.call_function(C:/Users/Abi/AppData/Local/Temp/sketch_190727c1462189324264258430/sketch_190727c.pyde)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:171)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1614)
    at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java:1658)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:276)
    at jycessing.PAppletJythonDriver.processSketch(PAppletJythonDriver.java:230)
    at jycessing.PAppletJythonDriver.findSketchMethods(PAppletJythonDriver.java:590)
    at jycessing.Runner.runSketchBlocking(Runner.java:398)
    at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.lambda$2(SketchRunner.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.convertPythonSketchError(SketchRunner.java:224)
    at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.lambda$2(SketchRunner.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```
````

Comment: always keep the calls inside methods

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, thank you @KevinWorkman

Answer (score 1):

Think about when the `saveFrame()` function is being called.

You've put the call to `saveFrame()` at the same level as your declarations of the `setup()`, `draw()`, and `mousePressed()` functions. That means you're calling `saveFrame()` **before** those other functions are called. That's what's causing your `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, you probably want to move your `saveFrame()` call so it's inside your `mousePressed()` function.

By the way, this is a **runtime error**, not a compiler error.